# Java byte[] rendered to react

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

I have found some similar questions, but none solves the problem that I am facing.

Here is the issue, on my backend I have an endpoint in java that returns an image in the form of a java byte array (byte[]). Hitting the endpoint with postman indeed just renders the image in the response.

My frondend is react with typescript. I cannot pass this url directly to the rendering because the endpoint involves security. Hence, I fetch the byte array with axios.

So far so good, the response.data of the endpoint holds the byte array. The array is not base64 encoded. it looks like this:

[image]

I was expecting once I had the byte array in react to be able to render it but this is not the case.
I tried to convert it like this

```
this.setState({image: "data:image/png;base64," + data;})
```

or like this

```
this.setState({image: "data:image/png;" + data;})
```

Both of those failed.
I tried to convert the input in Uint8Array.

```
var myArray= new Uint8Array(response.data);
```

The result was an empty array.

I tried to convert to base 64 and then process it

```
var base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, myArray));
```

This one failed.

What I have not tried is to save the image  in my path and render it from there, but this is not a solution that I want to go towards, since I want my backend to hold these data.

Is it possible to process a java byte array somehow?

**EDIT:**
My api call

```
await axios.get('localhost:8080/image', { headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + token} }
```

The java spring boot endpoint

```
@GetMapping(value = "/image", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public byte[] getAvatar(){
        return userFacade.getAvatar();
    }
```

The response in postman is not json, it just renders the image when called.
[image]

Comment: Could you provide us with more information about how the image data is encoded in the first place on the Java side?

Comment: @dsillman2000 The images are saved via another endpoint, they are going in as input stream and are converted to byte[] using `byte[] bytesImage = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);` Then this array is returned via another endopoint. Is that clear or you need more information?

Comment: You might be in the market for a `Uint8ClampedArray`, as detailed in this MDN article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData

Comment: @dsillman2000 I will try it an update my answer.

Comment: @dsillman2000 Unfortunately does not work 
 `myarray = response.data; let myImage = new ImageData(myarray, 72, 72);` Throws the following exception.   Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to construct 'ImageData': cannot convert to dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

> So far so good, the response.data of the endpoint holds the byte array. The array is not base64 encoded. it looks like this:

Let's talk about what's actually in there. All you've shown us is: "If I take whatever mystery meat is in the `x.data` reference and toss it at the java debugger console, this gobbledygook comes out", which **does not** actually explain what you actually have. It merely explains what the result of invoking toString on what you actually have would render, which in this case is insufficient information to work backwards and make good conclusions about what you actually have.

There are a few ways it could have gone, but presumably, as you said you 'got it from axios', this data perhaps arrived via JSON.

**JSON does not do byte arrays**, so that's quite the problem. You simply cannot ship them. I have no idea what happens if you try - the undoubtedly correct API take is that the code path that handles 'hey, this API wants this `byte[]` relayed to it via this JSON based mechanism' should have thrown something. It evidently didn't, so some part in the chain is badly designed. Sucks, so, work around that.

The obvious candidate is that something somewhere along the chain got the byte array and converted it to a string instead. **This is very dangerous**: *LOTS* of APIs, in many languages make this easy, and that is an erroneous API design. It should not be easy to silently / implicitly convert strings to byte arrays and back (in fact, a whole bunch of languages, including e.g. python2, consider byte arrays and strings synonyms, which is an extremely silly idea that leads to lots of confusiong and hard-to-find bugs!).

Find the place that did that, and stop doing it. To convert byte arrays to strings, you need two things:

1. You need to be sure the byte array contains actual text. If it does contain actual text, then you must know the encoding of that text. Once you know this, you can convert it to a string, apply an escape mechanism to the string, and you are now free to send the data in string form. Ensure the data transfer mechanism is *actually* string based first, of course; if it's byte[] based don't convert anything and just send the byte[] verbatim (most data transfer mechanisms ARE byte[] based; JSON is an exception to this rule!)
2. If it does NOT contain actual text (it doesn't here), then no charset encoding is appropriate. If it must be transferred in string form, use an encoding mechanism such as, yes, Base64. The incoming data isn't Base64, so we can conclude:

Somebody somewhere in the chain decided to write code that transfers a `byte[]` by applying some unknown (and, as the byte array did not represent text content, by definition incorrect) charset encoding to it.

You've already lost the game when you got this far. Go back into the call chain that you got here and fix it 'upstream' to to speak.

If you truly cant, then it's time to acknowledge that you're writing a workaround for a known-buggy backend you can't currently fix. Accept that you'll have to write error-prone code that needs a ton of tests and will remain a fragile part of your infrastructure, and accept that you'll probably have to write weird (i.e. lots of comments are a good idea here) code that isn't pretty and probably won't be using many industry standards. Also, aggressively isolate the code so you can properly explain that it exists to work around bug X in framework Y and should not be used for anything except to work around said bug.

You *may* be able to reconstitute the image by taking your gobbledygook and applying a series of `String -> byte[]` and `byte[] -> String` conversions, back and forth, using different charsets, until you end up at the source `byte[]`. This *MAY* not be possible; these conversions (at least one has already been applied by the backend!) can be lossy, and if data has been lost, well, unless you're a wizard, what's gone is gone.

> Here is the issue, on my backend I have an endpoint in java that returns an image in the form of a java byte array (byte[]).

So, this is simply not how it works, unless 'an endpoint' is 'a method invocation on this very JVM'. Assuming 'an endpoint' is e.g. an HTTP API endpoint or similar, those fundamentally do not talk in terms of java types. They have their own typing system. For example, if it's JSON-over-HTTP, that'll be a string, which contains dictionaries, lists, booleans, doubles, null, and strings - with the keys of all dictionaries being strings and the values of all dictionaries and lists being, recursively, anything of the defined set. None of this includes anything that even remotely acts like a java `byte[]`.

### Steps to take

1. Explain precisely how the flow of code goes - you make some request somewhere, that request goes through a bunch of layers until it eventually hits some java code that has an instance of `byte[]`, which then travels back through these layers and ends up in your javascript code. Explain each layer and how it works. This may involve doing some research. You should do this.
2. Double check what you actually have. Something like `console.log(typeof data)` would be a useful start, if it's an object, consider inspecting its `prototype` chain; that's more or less javascript's version of java's `.getClass()`.
3. Most likely result is that you have a string object in the javascript side. Delve into the code as described by #1, and find the place that converted that `byte[]` into `String` form. It is probably in code you didn't personally write. Fix your use of this API to not convert like this.

In general, attempting to transfer large binary data in JSON is a very bad idea (it is slow and inefficient), but if you must, the easiest fire-and-forget solution here is to apply base64-encoding server-side at the right place (the place you found for #3), and base64-decode client-side.

Comment: Hi @rzwitserloot, thanks for your answer, the endpoint of the java does not return json, it returns byte[], it is endpoint to return image, so the data indeed are unparsable to String. I posted it mainly because most of the answers involved base64 conversions. I know that till the endpoint works, because hitting the endpoint with postman renders the image (I will update the question with a printscreen). I have not researched if axios does some kind of conversion on the incoming data, you might be right on that, I will update the code with my axios api call. And the result of the type of data.

Comment: I have explained in the comments that in java the input stream of the image is converted to byte[] and then this is returned. How would you change that?

Comment: I have edited the question, with extra information.

Comment: Your answer is on the right track, the axios converts the bytearray to string, so I guess this might cause errors. I will have to do some research to see how to prevent it from doing so.